# Spring cloud contract - json headers mangled

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm writing a contract test that requires json headers to be passed in request. Example contract:

```
Contract.make{
    request {
        headers {
            contentType("application/json")
            header("Custom-Header", ["a": 10, "b": "11"])
        }
        ...
    }
    response {
        ...
    }
}
```

This generates request with invalid JSON header:

```
MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given()
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .header("Custom-Header", "[a:10, b:11]")
```

How can I make sure the request is built with EXACT json that I describe in the contract?

Comment: From what I remember we don't really support multiple values of a single header via the Groovy map notation. You can put there multiple values in a form of a String and try again. If that works then it means that this is an issue to be fixed.

Comment: I did not mention this, but using a simple string (replacing `["a": 10, "b": "11"]` in the header call with `'{"a":10,"b": "11"}'`) still generates the same request.

Comment: Can you show exactly how your generated test looks like if you do that?

Comment: It's exactly the same as posted above.

Comment: Strange... can you file an issue here please https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues ?